# Grails searchable relationship

Tags: grails, searchable

I am wondering how to return specific domain with searchable?
For example we have domain A and B. Both domain are searchable and have relationship: A has many B and B belongs to A. Another case A and B have many-to-many relationship.

Now when I search for item, I must always return A item. In my case let say I found matches in B, I need to return all As for each B. Other way around should work as well.

Currently I do a search query is searchable services:

```
def searchResults = searchableService.search(params.q, params)
```

Is there a way to get all related A domain for any search results?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Make both your domains(A & B) searchable and then add `DomainObject component:true` in searchable properties.

```
class A{
  String name

  static hasMany = [bclass: B]
  static searchable = {
     bclass component: true
  }
}

class B{
  String color

  static belongsTo= [aclass: A]
  static searchable = true
}
```

Suppose in **B** there are some rows with **color** field value as 'red'

```
A.search("red")
```

will return all the instances of **A**, which has its child class **B** with **color** field value as 'red'

Comment: I am using another domain to link A & B - C as a link table.
Can you give me example which includes link table?

Comment: Just use the same approach and search using domain.search(...).  Like for above example A.search(params.q,params) will match string from both domains A and B and will give output in terms of A even if the string matches in B domain.

Comment: Can you post an example? I would much appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer works only if you have 2 domain. I have 3 domain:
A <->> C <<-> B where C contains only link ids. How do I make B component of A if there is no direct link?